Trouble detecting how long a computer has been idle in PowerShell
I found this article (Get idle time of machine) about getting the idle time of a computer using PowerShell.
What I want to do is check if the computer has been idle for 1 hour, and if so, put the computer to sleep. I created a script that I believe should accomplish this, based on what I have read through the article and linked sites.
I'm running into an issue using it to sleep my computer when I want. For some reason, When the computer has been idle for 30 minutes, it returns a timespan indicating it has been idle for over an hour. I can't for the life of me figure out why.
Any ideas on what would be causing this or how I can fix it? It doesn't seem like anyone else in that thread had this issue which is concerning to me, haha. I've included the script and the last few lines of the log file below.
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvoke.Win32 {

    public static class UserInput {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=false)]
        private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct LASTINPUTINFO {
            public uint cbSize;
            public int dwTime;
        }

        public static DateTime LastInput {
            get {
                DateTime bootTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);
                DateTime lastInput = bootTime.AddMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);
                return lastInput;
            }
        }

        public static TimeSpan IdleTime {
            get {
                return DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(LastInput);
            }
        }

        public static int LastInputTicks {
            get {
                LASTINPUTINFO lii = new LASTINPUTINFO();
                lii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));
                GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);
                return lii.dwTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
'@
do{
Log-IdleState c:\sleeplog.txt
if(([PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleTime) -ge (new-timespan -hours 1)){
    Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState("Suspend", $false, $true)
}
start-sleep -seconds 10
} while(1 -eq 1)

No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:55:58 | Detected idle for : 00:25:52.4530000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:56:08 | Detected idle for : 00:26:02.4840000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:56:18 | Detected idle for : 00:26:12.5160000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:56:28 | Detected idle for : 00:26:22.5470000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:56:38 | Detected idle for : 00:26:32.5780000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:56:48 | Detected idle for : 00:26:42.6090000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:56:58 | Detected idle for : 00:26:52.6410000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:57:08 | Detected idle for : 00:27:02.6870000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:57:18 | Detected idle for : 00:27:12.7190000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:57:28 | Detected idle for : 00:27:22.7340000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:57:38 | Detected idle for : 00:27:32.7500000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:57:48 | Detected idle for : 00:27:42.7810000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:57:58 | Detected idle for : 00:27:52.8280000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:58:08 | Detected idle for : 00:28:02.8440000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:58:18 | Detected idle for : 00:28:12.8590000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:58:28 | Detected idle for : 00:28:22.8910000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:58:38 | Detected idle for : 00:28:32.9220000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:58:48 | Detected idle for : 00:28:42.9370000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:58:58 | Detected idle for : 00:28:52.9840000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:59:08 | Detected idle for : 00:29:03.0310000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:59:18 | Detected idle for : 00:29:13.0620000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:59:28 | Detected idle for : 00:29:23.0940000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:59:38 | Detected idle for : 00:29:33.1250000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:59:48 | Detected idle for : 00:29:43.1560000
No Action performed at 05/10/2024 11:59:58 | Detected idle for : 00:29:53.1870000
Slept at 05/10/2024 12:00:02 | Detected idle for : 1.03:56:12.4680000


What is Log-IdleState?  Is it the the code producing your output?  If so, it may be your problem.

It is my function to record to the log file. Not relevant as it breaks after 30 minutes whether it is present or not.

Are you aware that sendig a computer to sleep after a particular idle time is a builtin feature in Windows?

Wouldn't you be better of posting this as a C# question, PowerShell is only acting as a wrapper in your code?
